# Printing Text from a file into a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a chat on my website and I have code that will allow the user to enter the text and submit it by pressing enter. The input works along with the writing of the input into a file with php, however the function that is supposed to add the inputs from the file into the  doesn't seem to be working. It adds the nickname of the user, but the message that the user entered never appears. What am I doing wrong?

I have already been trying to figure this out for 2 days now. Thank you in advance!

Javascript/JQuery:

```
    var instanse = false;
    var file = 'data.txt'
    function Chat() {
        /* call update chat function */
        this.update = updateChat;
        /* call send chat function */
        this.send = sendChat;
        /* call get state function */
        this.getState = getState;
    }
    //define get state function
    function getState() {
        if(!instanse){
            instanse = true;
            /* define AJAX function */
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {'function': 'getState', 'file': file},
                dataType: "json",  
                success: function(data) {state = data.state;instanse = false;}
            });
        }
    }
    //define update chat function
    function updateChat() {
        if(!instanse){
            instanse = true;
            /* define AJAX function */
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {'function': 'update','state': state,'file': file},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.text){
                        /* manage data */
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                            $('#chat-row').append($(""+ data.text[i] +""));
                        }  
                    }
                    /* manage position of current chat */
                    document.getElementById('chat-row').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-row').scrollHeight;
                    instanse = false;
                    state = data.state;
                }
            });
        }
        else {
        setTimeout(updateChat, 1000);
        }
    }
    //define send chat function
    function sendChat(msg, name) { 
        updateChat();
        /* define AJAX function */
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            /* manage message */
            data: {'function': 'send','message': msg,'nickname': name,'file': file},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                updateChat();
            }
        });
    }
//--------------------
    // open popup prompt for ask name of user    
        var name = prompt("Enter your name:", "Guest");
        // default name is 'Guest'
        if (!name || name === ' ') {
            name = "Guest";  
        }
        // strip tags
        name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        // display name on page
        $("#user-name").html("User: <strong>" + name + "</strong>");
        var chat = new Chat()
        $(function() {
            chat.getState(); 
            /* define function when key presses */
            $("#posttext").keydown(function(event) {  
                var key = event.which;  
                /* if key including return. */
                if (key >= 33) {
                    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = this.value.length;  
                    /* define limit of new content */
                    if (length >= maxLength) {  
                        event.preventDefault();  
                    }  
                }  
            });
            /* define function when key release */
            $('#posttext').keyup(function(e) {  
                if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
                    var text = $('#posttext').val();
                    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 
                    // send 
                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
                        chat.send(text, name);  
                        $(this).val("");
                    } 
                    else {
                        $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
                    }  
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$function = $_POST['function'];
$log = array();
switch($function) {
    /* get state case */
    case('getState'):
        /* check file available or not */
        if (file_exists('data.txt')) {
            /* assign to variable */
            $lines = file('data.txt');
        }
        $log['state'] = count($lines); 
        break;
    /* update case */
    case('update'):
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        /* check file available or not */
        if (file_exists('data.txt')) {
            /* assign to variable */
            $lines = file('data.txt');
        }
        $count =  count($lines);
        if ($state == $count){
            /* if state & count are equal */
            $log['state'] = $state;
            $log['text'] = false;
        } else {
            /* if state & count are no equal */
            $text= array();
            $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;
            foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
                if ($line_num >= $state){
                    $text[] =  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                }
            }
            $log['text'] = $text; 
        }
        break;
    /* send case */
    case('send'):
        $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
        $message = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
        if (($message) != "\n") {
            if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) {
                $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message);
            } 
            fwrite(fopen('data.txt', 'a'), "<div>". $nickname . "</div> \n" . $message);
        }
        break;
}

echo json_encode($log);
```

Comment: Are you saying you are writing to a text file to save these chats?

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes. The PHP is writing the username and message to the data.txt file and that works fine. My problem is that the UpdateChat function is only able to get the username from the file not the message.